# How can I bypass a Jscript version check?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jscript

I have a website with a well-known bug in the code that checks for browser compatibility. This is the offending piece of code:

```
strScriptEngineVer = ScriptEngineMajorVersion() + '.' + ScriptEngineMinorVersion();
if (ScriptEngineMajorVersion() < 5 || ScriptEngineMinorVersion() < 5)
{
    AddTestResultRow('ScriptEngine',
    'Error',
    'Script Engine', // TRANS: msgScriptEngine
    strScriptEngineVer,
    // TRANS: msgScriptEngineWrongVersion
    'Your version of MS Script Engine is not sufficient, Centricity Enterprise Web will not function correctly.');
    // TRANS: msgErrorCannotGoOn
    ShowStopMessage('There is an error, Centricity Enterprise Web cannot go on.');
    return false;
}
```

This code causes Internet Explorer 9 to fail, because the Jscript engine version is 9.0. While logically, 9.0 is greater than 5.8 (IE 8), the above code fails because the "minor version" is reported as 0, and 0 is less than 5. What I would like to do (if it's possible) is to bypass this check by reporting a different Jscript version, or perhaps injecting javascript code to replace the broken code. I know it's possible to do the latter within IE's developer mode (see: https://braininstitute.mch.com/wiki/Centricity_Enterprise_Web), but I need a more automated approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define your own `ScriptEngineMajorVersion()`: `function ScriptEngineMajorVersion() { return 999; }`. Then yell at the developers, that's some pretty stupid code.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on exactly where this code is executed in comparison to where `ScriptEngineMinorVersion` is defined. But if it's something like the following:

```
<!-- ScriptEngineMajorVersion and ScriptEngineMinorVersion 
     are defined in tools.js //-->
<script src="tools.js"></script>
<script>
  if (ScriptEngineMajorVersion() < 5 || ScriptEngineMinorVersion() < 5)
  {
    /// ...
  }
</script>
```

Then you can just override the existing `ScriptEngineMajorVersion` and `ScriptEngineMinorVersion` functions. Like so:

```
<script src="tools.js"></script>
<script>
  function ScriptEngineMajorVersion(){
     return Infinity;
  }
  function ScriptEngineMinorVersion(){
     return Infinity;
  }
</script>
<script>
  if (ScriptEngineMajorVersion() < 5 || ScriptEngineMinorVersion() < 5)
  {
    /// ...
  }
</script>
```

But obviously it all depends on if you can inject your code between the definition and the use.